# iOS 7 - Modal popup with UIViewcontrollerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to present PopUp ViewController with animation, using UIViewcontrollerAnimatedTransitioning. I've created a Modal Segue from TableViewCell to my Viewcontroller

In PopupPresentAnimationController (that implement UIViewcontrollerAnimatedTransitioning) i have

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    [fromViewController addChildViewController:toViewController];
    toViewController.view.frame = fromViewController.view.frame;
    [fromViewController.view addSubview:toViewController.view];

    [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:fromViewController];

    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.6 initialSpringVelocity:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.5;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
}
```

The PopUpViewController have a background black with 50% opacity and, when it appear all "works" but after animation end, the screen become black.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
UIViewController *fromViewController =[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];

    CGRect initialFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
    initialFrame.origin.y = toViewController.view.frame.size.height;

    toViewController.view.frame = initialFrame;
    [container insertSubview:toViewController.view aboveSubview:fromViewController.view];

    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y = 0;
        toViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];
```

**UPDATE 2**
In prepareForSegue i have added the follow line

```
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom; // controller is the destination
```

With this line on, the black is no more black!

Comment: add update 2 as an ANSWER!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that you are adding your `toViewController` to the `fromViewController`. When the animation ends, the `toViewController` is removed and in turn, so is your `fromViewController`. The proper way to handle this is to use the container view provided by the context:

```
UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];
```

This is an example of how to do a popup transition:

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
  UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
  UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
  UIView *container = [transitionContext containerView];

  if (!self.beingDismissed) {
    //Make controller hidden so it can slide in
    CGRect initialFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
    initialFrame.origin.y = toViewController.view.frame.size.height;

    toViewController.view.frame = initialFrame;
    [container insertSubview:toViewController.view aboveSubview:fromViewController.view];
  }
  [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    if (!self.beingDismissed) {
        //Show view controller
        CGRect newFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y = 0;
        toViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
    } else {
        //Hide view controller
        CGRect newFrame = fromViewController.view.frame;
        newFrame.origin.y = fromViewController.view.frame.size.height;
        fromViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
    }
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];
  }];
}
```

Comment: i've tried this solution but when the popup appear, the view become totally black when animation finish...

Comment: Can you update your question with how you have adapted your code?

Comment: i have updated. Because i havent beginDismissed ecc, i have added all the code you have wrote (less the part for Hide View Controller).